# Uploading code from platform IO to esp32

Tags: visual-studio-code, uploading, esp32, platformio

I'm sorry for that stupid question but I really can't find what I need.

I made a code to use a `ESP Wrover 32` with PlatformIO/VScode and I need to upload the code to the `ESP32` (connected to the computer using USB) but I can't find how to select the right USB port to upload the code.

The error is :

> Please specify 'upload_port' for environment or use global
>   '--upload-port' option.

I tried to use the command lines but nothing works.

How can I upload my code ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I have the same issue on MAC computer. However, there is no problem on Windows.

Comment: I can't remember, sorry. I think it finally worked but don't know what I did

Answer (score 3):

To find the USB port: Hit `WindowsKey-X`, select `Device Manager`, plug in the device and observe what's listed under `Ports (COM & LPT)` - the one that just appeared has the port in brackets (COMn).

Then in platformio.ini in your PlatformIo initialised project folder, you specify the port as a line under the platform section (env: square brackets line): `upload_port = com9` or whatever you got from Device Manager.

I hope this helps.